# Code doesn't exists in TFS, although it was commited

Tags: commit

We are using TFS as source control, and SourceTree to for commit/push code changes.

We have found several cases, were we commit/push changes, and able to see them in TFS History. But when view the content of the file that was changed, it doesn't have the relevant changes.

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: I've had the same problem with TFS (although not using a git repo).  If you delete the file and check it out again, do you get the correct changes?

Comment: No. The missing code is in the source control, therefore it won't help to check it out again. I added the changes again and it solved the issue. But it repeated again in other files

Comment: I didn't mean remove the file from source control, I meant delete the files locally and check them out again.   We found that 2 people had different views of the same TFS file system.  The only way to get them to be both correct was delete all local files and checkout again.

Comment: I still didn't exactly understand the solution. If I remove it locally how it can solve the issue in TFS?  I already fixed manually the file by adding the code again..   Anyway, I'm trying to understand the source cause for this. How it happen?